# Convert int32 to int

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I need to convert int32 to int in VS2008 C++ CLI?

How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a cast:

```
int32 a = ...;
int b = (int) a;
```

Note that in principle this might lead to problems if you're running on a platform where `int` is less than 32 bits, but that's unlikely if it's a program for Windows.

Answer (score 6):

The C++/CLI keyword `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`.  No conversion or casting is necessary.

Comment: This is preferable to a cast as the compiler should complain at you it anything ever changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = (int) int32value;
```